# SaltStack - Creating custom windows Definitions File

Tags: windows, salt-stack

I'm using Salt to install a windows only software called Alteryx.

I've created an `/srv/salt/alteryx/alteryx.sls` as follows:

```
alteryx:
  '2018.3.4':
     installer: 'salt://win/repo/alteryx/Rinstaller_2018.3.4.51585.exe'
     full_name: Alteryx Designer 2018.3.4
     reboot: False
     installer_flags: '/S /l="C:\temp\alteryxInstall.log'
```

My saltstatck file is in `/srv/salt/alteryx/init.sls` is simply

```
alteryx:
  - pkg.installed
```

When I try to apply this state (`salt -G 'roles:alteryx' state.apply`) I get the following error:

```
 hostname
   Data failed to compile:
 --------
   ID alteryx in SLS alteryx is not a dictionary
```

I've tried placing the alteryx file in `/srv/win/repo-ng/salt-winrep-ng/`.  But I get the same error.

What else do I need to do to get this package installed?

Answer (score 0):

First of, if you have a look at [sample package definition sls file](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html#creating-a-package-definition-sls-file), there is no `installer_flags` argument. It should be `install_flags` instead.

Second, Salt doesn't distribute `SLS` file for windows packages itself, you need to sync them across manually every time a change is made.

From your `Saltmaster` run,

```
salt-run winrepo.update_git_repos
```

Run `pkg.refresh_db` on each of your Windows minions to synchronize the package repository.

```
salt -G 'os:windows' pkg.refresh_db
```

Please have a [read at this](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html#install-windows-software) as well.

Comment: Thanks.  In addition to the typo you pointed out. my `alteryx\init.sls` was malformed.  `pkg.installed` should not have been a list item but rather a dictionary item.

Comment: But now it can't find the installer file.  `Unable to cache `/win/repo/alteryx/<installer>.exe`

Comment: can you show the complete error? did you run above two commands?

Comment: I moved the file from `/srv/salt/win/repo/...` to `/srv/salt/alteryx/files/` and updated the `win/repo-ng/.../alteryx.sls` file to match and it now works.  But this means my files are not co-located with the description.  I did run the above commands.  I also ran `salt-run winrepo.genrepo` to see if that helped things along.